# Why is my Crontab not running at a specific time?

Tags: python-3.x, cron

I have the following cron running that works:

`*/2 * * * * cd /toThePath && /usr/bin/env python3 /toThePath test.py`

when I have this:

`0 16 * * * cd /toThePath && /usr/bin/env python3 /toThePath test.py`

It does not send at 16h00. I have tried 0 16 */1 */1 */1.

My script does include `#!/usr/bin/env python3` in the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Try running this in terminal.

```
date
```

Does the time displayed match your time zone?

Comment: No it does not, and that is causing my error. 

Thanks